# Ending a While Loop if a Condition is Not Met

Tags: python

I am trying to end a while loop if a condition is not met.

The purpose of this code is to get the most out of a multiple subjects without going over the maximum hours of work a student is willing to put in.

I have created a dictionary called "subjects" which maps out a certain subject to (value, work) with value as how valuable the subject is, and work as how much work is needed to put into that subject. I am adding up the values of the subjects without going over the maximum hours the student is willing to put in. The subjects that make the most sense are then put into a different dictionary.

Here is the code:

```
def greedyAdvisor(subjects, maxWork, comparator):
"""
Returns a dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work) which includes
subjects selected by the algorithm, such that the total work of subjects in
the dictionary is not greater than maxWork.  The subjects are chosen using
a greedy algorithm.  The subjects dictionary should not be mutated.

subjects: dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work)
maxWork: int >= 0
comparator: function taking two tuples and returning a bool
returns: dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work)
"""

bestVal = {}
tempVal = 0
high = 0
count = 0
tempDict = {}
tempWork = 0
currentBest = None
done = False

while done == False:

    for k in range(len(subjects)+1):
        for i in subjects:
            for j in subjects:
                if i not in bestVal:
                    sub1 = subjects[i][0]
                    sub2 = subjects[j][0]
                    work1 = subjects[i][1]
                    work2 = subjects[j][1]
                    if tempWork >= maxWork:
                            print('tempWork is', tempWork)                         
                            print('bestVal is', bestVal)
                            print('high is', high)
                            print('tempVal is', tempVal)
                            print()
                            return
                    print('sub1 is', sub1)
                    print('sub2 is', sub2)
                    print('work1 is', work1)
                    print('work2 is', work2)
                    maxVal = comparator(sub1, sub2)
                    print('count is', count)
                    count += 1
                    if maxVal == True:
                        print('sub1+tempVal is', sub1+tempVal)
                        print('tempVal is', tempVal)
                        print()
                        if work1 + tempWork > tempWork and tempWork + work1 <= maxWork:
                                high += tempVal+sub1
                                tempWork += work1
                                tempVal = sub1 +tempVal
                                print('sub1', sub1)
                                print('work1 is', work1)
                                print('tempWork is', tempWork)
                                print('tempVal is', tempVal)
                                print('tempWork is', tempWork)
                                bestVal[i] = subjects[i]
                                print('bestVal is', bestVal)
                                print()
                        else:
                            break
```

The loop ends if maxWork is met, which I have in the code already. The problem is, if maxWork is not met after going through all the subjects, it will continue to loop forever. I need to end the loop after all the items in the dictionary have looped and the condition is not met. I'm guessing I need an "if" statement here, but I just don't know how to write it. "If all the subjects have been tested and maxWork > tempWork: done = True"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just set `done = True` after all loops.

```
done = False

while not done:
    # your bunch of loops code here
    done = True
```

Further more. Are you really need the `while` loop? I cannot understand your code completely as it is too much to read but I see only `for` loops inside `while` and it looks like other things never change.

Comment: I know it is a mess, I was just stuck on this while loop thing and needed to just know how to do it, even if I didn't need it. I'm going to go back and clean it up. I appreciate the help.

Comment: sorry but this is a bad patch. The while loop is absolutely unnecessary

Comment: @joaquin if you read the whole answer and the comments you will notice that we all agree.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `done = True` after the last `for` loop should be sufficient, but your code has other problems.

The `while` loop is totally unnecessary. If you remove it, the code should work as desired.

You've also got three loops based on the number of subjects, so your total iterations (withou the `while`) is going to be the number of subjects cubed. That means that if you have 100 subjects, the innermost section has to execute 1 million times if a match isn't found. I really don't see the purpose of the "k" loop. You don't appear to be doing anything with that value, so it's just repeating the inner loops unproductively.

Comment: OK, got it. I took the while loop out and it also worked the same way as I needed it to. But I feel like I had to have tried that and it didn't work.  I probably overlooked something. But I was really stuck on this while loop thing. I'm just glad I got an answer to that, it was really bugging me. I'm go going to go over it again and clean it up. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I took out the while and the "k" loop and it only looped 248 times compared to 2300 times. Much more efficient. Thanks for the help

Comment: @CastorTroy IMHO, this one is the answer to be selected as the best

Answer (score 1):

You've written far too much code!

You might want to split how your code works: first sort the subjects in goodness order (perhaps using the `sorted` function which takes a `cmp` parameter), then go through the sorted list adding them to a result variable stopping when you would go above maxWork. You won't have the terminating problem that you're currently having because you'll naturally stop once you've finished going through the sorted list.

Often, breaking what you're doing into logically separate bits (here, sorting first then aggregating the result second) gives you simpler and easier to understand code.

Comment: Very true. This is just the way I started it, and as I made progress I couldn't go back...even if it is a mess. Thanks for the help.